# Unicode halves swapped, force it one way

Tags: php, unicode

I am using

```
bin2hex(iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2", $symbol))
```

for generating hash from Unicode symbols. An it worked fine up until I noticed that my development and production machines generate different hashes.

```
echo bin2hex(iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2", '好'));
```

generates `597d` on one and `7d59` on another machine.

This is bad (and totally unexpected), because I need to have their db interchangeable. I already indexed everything (quite a lot) with it and I am thinking what can be done about it.

Is it possible to force one way for this hashing?

If it is possible I will redo only one machine. If not, I have to use different algorithm, something like `substr(md5($symbol), 0, 4)` and redo everything.

Comment: Properly "UCS-2" in just an abstract coding (to 16bit integer). For a real (byte) encoding, you should use "UTF-16BE" or "UTF16LE" according CPU big endianess of little endianess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo bin2hex(iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2", '好'));` will output `7d59` if `好` (`$symbol`) is utf-8 encoded, and `597d` if the `好` character was already in `UCS-2`.

The problem is that your `$symbol` is not in UTF-8 when you get `597d`. It's a character encoding issue.

If in the machine that returns `597d` you change the code as `bin2hex($symbol)`, I guess it will output `7d59` instead.

Comment: I am pretty sure both my machines are UTF-8. They are 100% same code. One is windows (I am weak), other is linux. I'll check it.

Comment: Debug to confirm it: `var_dump($symbol, bin2hex($symbol), bin2hex(iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2", $symbol))),` - using the same symbol, in both envarioment, can you post here the results?

Comment: `string(3) "好" string(6) "e5a5bd" string(4) "7d59"` and `string(3) "好" string(6) "e5a5bd" string(4) "597d"`. I think problem is in encoding level ("UTF-8" to "UCS-2"). UCS-2 seems to differ dependent on system.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php

Comment: what if you try with http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php instead?

Comment: `mb_internal_encoding` seems to work on both systems identically. It uses code as my widnows machine with `iconv`.